# How to set STATISTICS_INCREMENTAL option ON for an index in SQL Server using c#?

Tags: index-statistics, smo

I need help with programmatically setting the STATISTICS_INCREMENTAL option ON for an index in a table in SQL Server (2016 SP2). I am using Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=13.0.0.0. I do not see any property in the Index class to enable STATISTICS_INCREMENTAL. I checked Version 140.17283.0 as well.

I am trying to periodically update statistics for only a few partitions using the command: UPDATE STATISTICS [Schema].[Table] IX_Table_Index
WITH RESAMPLE ON PARTITIONS(4). I enabled the Auto Create Incremental Statistics option at the database level. I just need help with enabled STATISTICS_INCREMENTAL at the index level.